# Best way to implement AWS ECS healthcheck

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-ecs

I'm implementing ECS health-check functionality and and I'm thinking about the best way to do that.

For now I have found several solutions:

1. Using [AWS ECS metrics and Dimensions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/ecs-metricscollected.html) and check whether some metric has insufficient value
2. Using CloudWatch Alarm:

---

```
ECSHealthAlarm:
Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm
Properties:
  AlarmDescription: Alarm for ECS StatusCheckFailed Metric
  ComparisonOperator: GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold
  EvaluationPeriods: 2
  Statistic: Maximum
  MetricName: StatusCheckFailed
  Namespace: AWS/ECS
  Period: 30
  Threshold: 1.0
  AlarmActions:
  - !Ref AlarmTopic
  InsufficientDataActions:
  - !Ref AlarmTopic
  Dimensions:
  - Name: ClusterName
    Value: !Ref ClusterName
  - Name: ServiceName
    Value: !GetAtt service.Name
```

3. Using CloudWatch event:

---

```
EventRule:
Type: "AWS::Events::Rule"
Properties:
  Name: CloudWatchRMExtensionECSStoppedRule
  Description: "Notify when ECS container stopped"
  EventPattern:
    source: ["aws.ecs"]
    detail-type: ["ECS Task State Change", "ECS Container Instance State Change"]
    detail:
      clusterArn: [ 'clusterArn' ]
      lastStatus: [ "STOPPED" ]
      stoppedReason: [ "Essential container in task exited" ]
      group: [ 'service-group' ]
  State: "ENABLED"
  Targets:
    - Arn: !Ref ECSAlarmSNSTopic
      Id: "PublishAlarmTopic"
      InputTransformer:
        InputPathsMap:
          stopped-reason: "$.detail.stoppedReason"
        InputTemplate: '"This micro-service has been stopped with the following reason: <stopped-reason>"'
```

Could you please advice whether those variants are correct or there is ant other way to do that more efficient? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is the health check for an AWS load balancer or for some other monitoring solution? AWS load balancers do not need complicated solutions. Just a simple HTML file is enough.

Answer (score 2):

I am not able to put comment, so here are some thoughts. I am bit unclear of your requirement, whether you are looking for alerts from EC2 server level status check or each ECS service tasks level. I am adding all the possible options here.

1. I would run ECS cluster EC2 instances under an Auto-Scaling Group and based on ASG CloudWatch metrics, setup a SNS notification when instances are being added/removed.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/healthcheck.html

2. We can have AWS ecs-agent docker container logs also sent to CloudWatch and get some SNS notifications based on errors or filtered events.
3. We can have subscription to CW from ECS event stream as well when each service tasks being started/stopped. References - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/cloudwatch_event_stream.html https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs_cwet.html

Example event entries are in below link – https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs_cwe_events.html

Reference for setting alarm based on log events.

https://medium.com/@martatatiana/insufficient-data-cloudwatch-alarm-based-on-custom-metric-filter-4e41c1f82050

Adding healthcheck for each ECS service wise and have containers restarted if they are not doing well.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html#container_definition_healthcheck

Please do let me know your thoughts as well :).